# Changes in Environment Variable is not working and applying - Windows 8

Tags: web, hugo

Hi I'm working with `hugo` and I will change the path variable but its not applying. My question is about the settings on path variable that is not working properly when i type to cmd

> echo %PATH%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show what was the echo %PATH% output ?

Please take note that you need to make sure that there is no character spaces between the path that you are setting. For example

Incorrect:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\; ;C:\Hugo\bin;

Correct:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Hugo\bin;

If it don't works just try to restart your command prompt then type

> echo %PATH% output

to see if it works.

Comment: also please refer to this existing thread but on windows 7
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685699/windows-7-environment-variable-not-working-in-path